# How to let a Meteor "room" know about an update

Tags: sockets, meteor, youtube-api

I'm building a similar app to togethertube.com and so far I have this

/profile, /rooms, /, /:roomname

Now, in each room I am using both the youtube player API and the youtube video search API, the rooms are loaded by a Mongo collection called "rooms", a Mongo collection called "videos" is associated to their own rooms so each time a room is loaded, their videos are loaded too.

The rooms collection has a field called "currentVideo" (and also "currentVideoTime") so, I want to let that particular room know when the currentVideo field changes so the view of each user who isn't the owner of that room and is currently viewing it changes and the youtube player API starts playing the new video.

I don't know how to do that, I've thought about sockets but the reason I started using Meteor is to avoid using socket.io but if that's the solution, so be it. Also tried thinking about using Meteor's Collection "Observe" so when the document corresponding to that room in the rooms collection is updated (when the video in the owner of the room's view finishes playing and the room's currentVideo is updated) a function is fired and the youtube player API loads that video.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this or is there a better Full-Stack framework that I can use to do something similar to dubtrack.fm and togethertube.com?

Answer (score 1):

[Collection.observeChanges()](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges) is the way to go. Note that Meteor already uses WebSocket so changes get pushed automatically from the server to all subscribed clients.